# Use VBO in Drupal to update custom user field

Tags: drupal

I want to perform bulk update of users with a Approved users, the table

```
field_user_status_value
-----------------------
entity_type, entity_id, field_user_status_value
```

The entity_id is the user id which does not exist in the table, below is the custom module I wrote to update the table:

```
function bulkapprove_action_info() {
  return array(
    'bulkapprove_action_callback_name' => array(
      'type' => 'user', // Can be file, term, user, etc.
      'label' => t('Approve User'),
      'configurable' => FALSE, // Doesn't need config form
      'behavior' => array('view_property'), // Uses view access rights  ,
      'pass rows' => TRUE,
      'triggers' => array('any'), // Works always
    ),
  );
}

function bulkapprove_action_callback_name($entity, $context) 
{
    db_update('field_data_field_user_status')->fields(array('field_user_status_value' => 'Approved'))->condition('entity_id', $context->entity_id)->execute();
}
```

But it is not inserting the values in this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal you do not want to update the database fields directly unless you created the table. Drupal's internal APIs provide a collection of tools to ensure you update the values correctly and that all supporting modules get notified of changes as needed through the hook system.

In this case the callback gets the actual entity to run your action against (in this case the user object). You want to take action on that entity and then save the entity.

```
function bulkapprove_action_callback_name($entity, $context) 
{
  $entity->status = 1;
  entity_save('user', $entity);
}
```